# Spring Security roles issue

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I overrode the method in the SpringWebConfig and I want to give all pages of application only for admins.

```
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/*", "/**").hasRole("ADMIN");
    }
```

When I try to open page http://localhost:8080/api/v1/skills/ without any authorization I have a correct result instead of 403. Maybe I'm wrong with my config?
Full project https://github.com/Wismut/crud_developers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the following class inside config package

```
package ua.wismut.config;

import org.springframework.security.web.context.AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer;

public class SecurityWebApplicationInitializer extends AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer {

}
```